# asp boundfield to store multiple value in same field

Tags: gridview

I am trying to retrieve data from database and show it like in a typical SHOPPING site.
Now for that i need a page to show the image and the name of the Category in ONE field.

This is my design of the Gridview

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">    
<columns>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Cat_id" HeaderText="ID" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Cat_name" HeaderText="Name" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Cat_desc" HeaderText="Description" />
    <asp:ImageField DataImageUrlField="Cat_filepath" ControlStyle-Width="100" ControlStyle-Height="100" HeaderText="Preview Image" />

    </columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

This is showing my Gridview with all the values in their respective fields, but i want the image and the cat_name in the same field, i can do it using TemplateField but i cannot retrieve the imageurlfield via TemplateField.

Please give a solution if you can

Answer (score 0):

Well, the question is quite old, but better late than never...

First, you need to switch the `HtmlEncode` off in the given column:

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="Cat_name" HeaderText="Name" HtmlEncode="false" />
```

And then you can create an `Image` control and render it directly in the `GridView`'s cell.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            DataTable dt = DataProvider.GetData();
            foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
            {
                var img = new Image()
                {
                    ImageUrl = row["Cat_filepath"].ToString(),
                    AlternateText = row["Cat_name"].ToString()
                };
                row["Cat_name"] += ControlsRenderer.RenderControl(img);
            }

            myGridView.DataSource = dt;
            myGridView.DataBind();
        }
    }

public static class ControlsRenderer
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Returns the generated HTML markup for a Control object
    /// </summary>        
    public static string RenderControl(Control control)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter(sb);
        HtmlTextWriter writer = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);

        control.RenderControl(writer);
        return sb.ToString();
    }
}
```